# how to make a string array in c with unknow array length and unknow string length? suppose memory is enough

Tags: c

if I want to store string array in C program from stdin, whose array length is not known in advance and the string length is unfixed or unlimited. That means I can not define such thing as char buf[10][100]; in the program. Is there any good solution for this case?

Comment: Use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: if you replace "unlimited" with "unknown, but restricted to less than *your available memory space*", there might be an answer. If you get to know the actual string size in advance, you can allocate an array of appropriate size beforehand and read into it. Otherwise you may have to read the input in a list of fixed size chunks and allocate the array after all input was read.

Comment: To begin with, you need to equip your computer with unlimited RAM cells. Go to the computer store and ask how much a computer with unlimited RAM costs.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't have such a function but [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which is POSIX does what you want. This may or may not be what you're looking for, depending on what OS you're planning to run this on.

You just do something like:

```
char *inf_line = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
ssize_t input = getline(&inf_line, &n, stdin);
```

Alternatively, you could try filling up an array with `getchar()` in some loop, dynamically reallocating memory as you reach the end of the array using `malloc()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

See the following code as an example how to read input until EOF is reached (in terminal, try <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to emulate an EOF, depending on your OS), by using fixed size chunks and creating a full string after the last chunk was read.

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 4 // testing size
//#define CHUNK_SIZE 1024 // my suggested production size

struct node
{
    char data[CHUNK_SIZE];
    struct node* next;
};

int main()
{
    // will be allocated and filled after reading all input
    char* full_text = NULL;
    // head node
    struct node* start = NULL;
    // iterator node
    struct node* current = NULL;
    // for tail allocation
    struct node** next = &start;
    // count the number of chunks (n-1 full and one partially filled)
    size_t count = 0;
    // size of the last read - will be the count of characters in the partially filled chunk
    size_t last_size;
    // will be initialized to the full text size (without trailing '\0' character)
    size_t full_size;
    while (!feof(stdin))
    {
        // casting malloc result is bad practice, but working with VS here and it's complaining otherwise
        // also, you may want to check the result for NULL values.
        *next = (struct node*)calloc(1, sizeof (struct node));
        last_size = fread_s((*next)->data, CHUNK_SIZE, 1/* sizeof char */, CHUNK_SIZE, stdin);
        next = &((*next)->next);
        ++count;
    }
    // calculate the full size and copy each chunk data into the combined text
    if (count > 0)
    {
        full_size = CHUNK_SIZE * (count - 1) + last_size;
        // one additional character for the null terminator character
        full_text = (char*)malloc(full_size + 1);
        full_text[full_size] = '\0';
        count = 0;
        current = start;
        while (current && current->next)
        {
            memcpy(&full_text[count * CHUNK_SIZE], current->data, CHUNK_SIZE);
            current = current->next;
            ++count;
        }
        if (current)
        {
            memcpy(&full_text[count * CHUNK_SIZE], current->data, last_size);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        full_text = (char*)calloc(1, 1);
    }
    // full_text now contains all text
    // TODO free the node structure

    return 0;
}
```

*side note: I use `calloc` instead of `malloc` so I get zero-initialized storage.*

*side note: I use the binary `fread_s` instead of `fgets`, which doesn't zero-terminate the read data (would need some different handling otherwise) and which may not play nice with non-ASCII input. So make sure you understand your input format when using this 1:1*

Comment: Why cast result of `malloc()`?

Comment: @RoadRunner As commented in the code above first allocation, I'm using Visual Studio right now, which comes with crappy intellisense, mixing up languages and highlighting un-casted allocation as an error even though I know it shouldn't

Comment: Okay, yeah that's fine. UV from me :).